# modern windowless popups

Tags: javascript, popup

I have seen for some time popups without window and it looks like a custom made png file as popup. many times there is a big close cross in the upper right corner.

Can someone tell me please how this is called and in what kind of code this is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually an html div that is popped up through Javascript, usually through plugins for a Javascript framework such as jQuery.  Here's a [tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial) of using one of the plugins.

Comment: This one is even more helpfull to me!

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to implement a pop over in JavaScript and most libraries now have built in support for such things, or have added support through plugins and mini-frameworks (lightbox).  Here are just a few by their respective libraries, of which, jQuery and Prototype have the best out-of-the-box support and features.

### jQuery

- [$.dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) (jQuery UI, generic dialog)
- [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) (plugin, handles images, flash, youtube, Quicktime, external sites)
- [jquery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) (plugin, handles images only)
- [thickbox](http://thickbox.net/) (plugin, lightbox alternative, handles images, frames, inline/ajax content)

### Prototype/Scriptaculous

- [lightview](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/) (mini-framework, handles Image, Flash, Quicktime, Ajax & Forms, Anti-aliasing, Iframe, Inline content)
- [lightwindow](http://www.p51labs.com/lightwindow/) (mini-framework, handles too many to list)
- [lightbox 2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) (mini-framework, handles images only)

### Dojo

- [dijit.Dialog](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Dialog) (dijit built-in, generic dialog)

### ExtJs

- [MessageBox](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/message-box/msg-box.html) (built-in, generic dialogs)
- [Ext.ux.DataView.LightBox](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=54977) (plugin, adhoc, alpha)

### YUI

- [YAHOO.widget.Dialog](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/dialog-quickstart.html) (built-in, generic)

Here's [another list](http://www.fortysomething.ca/mt/etc/archives/005400.php) with more/different plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost certainly looking at some form of Lightbox.  [This page](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/06/25-extensive-list-essential-pop-up-window-enhancements.html) has an extensive list of implementations.

Comment: I have thought about this sollution too, when I tried your link, something pops up, this is the link:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=446786

And this is indeed used with lightbox I guess. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

These are most easily created by javascript library plug-ins.

**Prototype** has [LightBox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)

**jQuery** used to have [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), but it is no longer maintained. Searching now for alternatives (the old page for ThickBox has several newer options)...

Answer (score 1):

I've typically heard them called *modal dialogs*.

There's a jquery library called [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).  It's very easy to use.

Comment: Great! this is where I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if people still call them DHTML pop-ups. Anyway, code for this kind of pop-up nowadays is usually very simple. The one I prefer is jQuery Tools. Here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in support, they're implemented using pure html, css, and javascript.  The easiest way to do this is to use an existing javascript library like the jquery (see [jquery's dialog box](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)) or another solution to create javascript, like GWT (see [Google Web Toolkit Dialog Box](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html))